# How to select a array of nodes using standard javascript methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a array of elements I would like to retrieve from a list, I am unable to change the elements, I would usually use jQuery and the call would be:

```
$("//div/ol/li/h3/a");
```

However I am unable to sue jquery or another selector framework for that matter, how should this be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** It seems that `//div/ol/li/h3/a` is an XPath expression, which is not supported anymore by jQuery afaik.

If your target browsers support it, you can simply use [`querySelectorAll` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('div > ol > li > h3 > a');
```

Otherwise, a direct conversion would be:

```
// root is the element you start with, e.g. `document.body`
var selector = ['ol', 'li', 'h3', 'a'],
    set = root.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i = 0, len = selector.length; i < len; i++) {
    var tag = selector[i],
        new_set = [];

    for(var j = 0, lenj = set.length; j < lenj; j++) {
        for(var child = set[j].firstChild; child; child.nextSibling) {
            if(child.nodeName.toLowerCase() === tag) {
                new_set.append(child);
            }
        }
    }

    set = new_set;
}
```

At the end, `set` will contain all links. One could also write a recursive function or simplify the code, if more information about the HTML structure is given.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, you want to get all div, ol, li, h3 or a elements from  your document in a single array without any dependencies on any javascript frameworks.

I think I would do something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/UP3nH/

---

**UPDATE**

@Felix Kling has pointed out that the OP is attempting to an use XPath selector in the question. *(this has been deprecated in more recent versions of JQuery)*

To create an array of elements that matched the XPath query `//div/ol/li/h3/a` you could do this.

```
var tags = ['ol', 'li', 'h3', 'a'];
var result = [];
var leafs = document.getElementsByTagName(tags[tags.length - 1]);

for (var i = 0; i < leafs.length; i++) {
    var a = leafs[i],
        j = (tags.length - 1);
    while (a && a.nodeName.toLowerCase() == tags[j].toLowerCase()) {
        j--;
        a = a.parentNode;
        if (j < 0) {
            result.push(leafs[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);​
```

Comment: `//div/ol/li/h3/a` seems to be a [XPath expression](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#XPath_Selectors) and `/` denotes a parent-child relationship.